# Fastest method to filter XmlDocument xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, xmldocument

I've got an XmlDocument object containing the following xml:

```
<xml>
    <People>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <Surname>Smith</Surname>
            <Type>A</Type>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
            <Surname>Smith</Surname>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>Chad</FirstName>
            <Surname>Smith</Surname>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>Tina</FirstName>
            <Surname>Johnson</Surname>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </Person>
    </People>
</xml>
```

I want to filter the xml where the Surname node is set to **Smith** and the Type is set to **B** into another XMLDocument object which looks like the following:

```
<xml>
    <People>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
            <Surname>Smith</Surname>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>Chad</FirstName>
            <Surname>Smith</Surname>
            <Type>B</Type>
        </Person>
    </People>
</xml>
```

What's the easiest / speediest method to filter my xml with the criteria mentioned above in C# ? Is there a way to do it in Linq? I tried to use SelectNodes and XPath but am not sure how to correctly write XPath expressions.

Thanks!

Edit: Figured it out:

```
descendant::Person[Surname='Smith' and Type='B']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication193
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement people = doc.Descendants("People").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> smith = people.Elements("Person").Where(x => (string)x.Element("Surname") == "Smith").ToList();

            people.ReplaceAll(smith);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! You missed out where I also check the Type. I've also figured out how to use xpath expressions which seems to work! `descendant::Person[Surname='Smith' and Type='B']`